# How can I display my MongoDB attributes?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, electron

I hosted my `Mongo` database in `mLab.com` with several collections as shown in the picture below:

[image]

I can't seem to be able to access "requests" collection. Here is what I have done:

first, I connected to the database and created the function in the main process (`main.js`):

```
mongoose.connect('url', { useMongoClient: true });

ipcMain.on('load-requests', function(event) {
  return Requests.find({}, { sort: {createdAt: -1}});
});
```

Inside another file called `schema.js` I have the following:

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var hosSchema   = new Schema({
    hospital: String,
    state: String,
    reasons: String,
    requestedDateTime: String,
    requestNumber: String,
    status: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Requests', hosSchema);
```

In the renderer process (`homePage.html`), I have the following:

```
<div id="page-inner">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                   <div class="card teal">
                        <div class="card-content white-text">
                          <span class="card-title">state</span>
                          <p>reason</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-action">
                          <a href="#">requestNumber</a>
                          <a href="#">requestedDateTime</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

I want to access `page-inner` through its `id` and change the attributes to their related once in the database. For example the state should be changed with the attributes retrieved from the function in the main process (`load-requests`).

How can I display the attributes inside `homePage.html`?

Answer (score 1):

In Schema.js:

```
var hosSchemaModel = mongoose.model('Requests', hosSchema);
module.exports = hosSchemaModel;
```

In main.js:

```
var hosSchemaModel = require("./Schema.js");
var getHosSchemas = function () {
    hosSchemaModel.find({}, function (err, hosSchema) {
          if (err) {
            //...
          } else {
            //Do something with the hosSchema 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks, what about the renderer process? how can I access the attributes of 'Requests'?